# Not able to see responsive Angular NVD3 chart with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have used NVD3 (http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarChart) library with bootstrap 3.0.
I have two div's of class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" aligned next to each other.
I want to display charts in both the div's.
Do display charts correctly i need to set height and width options for angular-nvd3 library.
It is working fine for desktop version.. but when i shrink the window size, it looses its responsiveness.

Again I cannot set width option in percentage; if i do so, it is not displaying chart.

```
// chart options
  $scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'multiBarChart',
      height: 250,
      width: 600,
      staggerLabels: false,
      transitionDuration: 1000,
      tooltips: true,
      tooltipContent: function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
        return '<p>' + key + ': ' + y + '</p>';
      },
      stacked: false,
      showControls: false,
      xAxis: {
        showMaxMin: false,
        axisLabel: 'MockTests',
        axisLabelDistance: -30
      },
      yAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Marks Comparison',
        axisLabelDistance: 40,
        ticks: 5,
        tickFormat: function(d) {
          return d3.format(',.f')(d);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a directive on the parent of your  tag and on resize, adjust the chart option width. I am not sure if it is the best option, but it helped me.

```js
.directive('flexibleDiv', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                opts: '=' 
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {

                // Watching height of parent div
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return element.parent(0).height();
                }, updateHeight);

                // Watching width of parent div
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return element.parent(0).width();
                }, updateWidth);

                function updateHeight() {
                    scope.opts.chart.height = element.parent(0).height()-150; //150 custom padding
                }

                function updateWidth() {
                    scope.opts.chart.width = element.parent(0).width()-50; //50 custom padding
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="card-content" flexible-div opts='optionsRequest'>
     <span class="card-title black-text">Request</span>
     <nvd3 options='optionsRequest' data='dataRequest'></nvd3>
</div>
```

[Please refer this](https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives/issues/146)

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't set any width in your chart options? From what I saw in the example on the NVD3 site, the width is not set so basically the chart is displayed having the width of its parent element.

Comment: yes.. I tried that also.. I removed width option but only partial chart is displaying.. as I have limited space and half of its size is occupied by another col-md-6 div